# (X subset of Y or Y subset of X) is transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

so I was trying to figure out how to prove something and I failed so because I think the statement is false.
anyways here is the statement :

[image]

[image]

[image]

To prove if the relation is Transitive we need to assume xRy and yRv and prove xRv.
so the assumption means that there are 4 options here :

(1) --> if x⊆y and y⊆v then x⊆v

(2) --> if y⊆x and v⊆y then v⊆x
The main problem of the proof comes here :
(3) --> if x⊆y and v⊆y then we can't prove x⊆v or v⊆x (I.e. x={1},v={2},y={1,2,3})
(4) --> if y⊆x and y⊆v then we can't prove x⊆v or v⊆x (I.e. y={1},v={1,2},x={1,3})

So we can't prove for all the scenarios which means its might be not transitive?
and if its not transitive then the relation is not considered as Partially ordered set or Equivalence relation.

Sorry for the long post , Am I right that its not transitive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The proof by a [counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample):

Let

$$
\begin{aligned}
X &= \{1\}\\
Y &= \,\;\emptyset\\
Z &= \{2\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then

- $X\pmb RY$ (because $Y\subset X$), and
- $Y\pmb RZ\,$ (because $Y\subset Z\;$), but
- **not** $X\pmb RZ$ (because neither $X\subset Z$, nor $Z\subset X$)).

Thus, the relation $\pmb R$ is **not** transitive.

Comment: Thank you very much,  have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not transitive, and the examples you already have in your question confirm that. For example, in your point 3,$xRy$ and $yRv$ but it is not true that $xRv$.

Comment: by the example I have shown it says that it sometimes works (xRv) and sometimes not so it means - not for every xRy and yRv it occurs so its not transitive right?

Comment: Yep. For it to be transitive, it has to work *for all* $x,y,v$. To prove that it is not transitive, it suffices to find *only one* counterexample (where it doesn't work).

Comment: Thank you very much,  have a nice day!

Comment: Please don't add “thanks” as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//math.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Mathematics way of saying thank you.